# When I clear rows, I lose cell's functions

Tags: vba, excel

I want to know how to save cells format when clearing rows from a table.I have a table with many columns and each column have a certain formula or function. And I have a button that refresh the table by clearing all old rows. So the problem is when I refresh I lose all the functions.

```
Public Sub refresh()
'
' refresh Macro
'
' Touche de raccourci du clavier: Ctrl+y
'
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lr1 As Long

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scénarios de menace")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analyse de risque S")

    ws2.Range("B6:AP" & ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Clear
    lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ws1.Range("A1:A" & lr1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="x"
        ws1.Range("B2:AP" & lr1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

        ws2.Range("B6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        ws1.Range("A6:A" & lr1).AutoFilter
        ws2.Activate: ws2.Cells(1, 1).Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: If i understand this right you have multiple columns with formulas in it but you need to clear old data. Is the data also in those specific columns or in a different column? if its in a different column why would you clear the formulas from the other columns and not just clear the data column.

Comment: it's a table with many columns and each column has a certain format ( like a list where we can choose one element or a formula that calculate an addition or something like that). So when I clear rows all this format disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Clear does what it says on the box. It clears the object. After it's done, the object has no values, no formats and no formulas.

If you want to retain formulas and formats, but keep the row, you need to clear the contents of the cells that have the constants, i.e. don't clear the whole row.

You may want to loop through each cell in the row or target them directly and use [ClearContents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff835589.aspx).

That seems like a waste of space, though.

In any case, using an Excel Table and deleting rows might be a better fit. Because, in an Excel Table, any new row will automatically inherit formulas and formats, so you can delete any row and add new rows that will perform automatically to the table setup.

Comment: How can I clear just the content ? Which function in vba should I use ?

Comment: That's not the issue. You cannot clear the whole row in your scenario if you want to retain the formats and functions. You will need to step through each cell in the row and delete it if it does not contain a formula. How to do that depends on your data structure.  Again, if you use an Excel table, you can delete whole rows and when you add a new row, formulas and formats will be applied automatically. Consider that as an alternative to your current approach.

Comment: Good info +1 (you should replace `Clear.Contents` with `ClearContents`)

Comment: Thanks @paulbica. Removed the dot.